# How to fix DAST - Proxy Disclosure and Timestamp Disclosure - Unix on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, content-security-policy

I'm recently working with Azure DevOps and we've set owasp zap on security side.
After scan, it returns this output like screenshot below. Thanks all.

On side Proxy Disclosure is below
[scan result proxy disclosure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUgWv.png)

On side Timestamp Disclosure - Unix is below
[scan result timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcUjU.png)

Thanks a lot for your feedback.

On my side, I configured my rules engine on our portal azure but it did not resolved my problem.

Below is the confiduration that I did.

[rules engine for app front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyZF9.png)